# SQLite - make true read only database

Tags: sqlite

I would like to open and read an SQLite .db file, read-only. I guarantee that nobody else will touch it during this time (perhaps, except for read only).

What I need from SQLite3 in return, is that it will write nothing to disk, ever (specifically - none of those described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)), and not use any file-system locks on the file.

Is that too much to ask?

Comment: We found this "Read-Uncommitted Isolation Mode", see http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html, which is supposed to solve this; however, it doesn't. SQLite still tries to use the lock APIs. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running under some Unix, you can use the [`unix-none` VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html) to disable all locking.

In Windows, SQLite always uses locks.
If you really want to avoid locks, you can either write your own VFS, or override the locking system calls with [`xSetSystemCall`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs.html).

If SQLite needs a temporary file, you cannot prevent it from creating one.
However, you can configure it to [create them in memory instead of on disk](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempstore).

Comment: Note: regarding your own VMS, you can fetch existing VMS using `sqlite_vfs_*` API and than only create a new `vtable` with your own locking function that does nothing. So that should be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

The VFS does not have a Lock method that can be injected. Therefore there is no a direct method to inject dummy LockFile and LockFileEx methods.

These methods are referenced inside sqlite3_io_methods (winIoMethod) and don't seem to be easy to modify in runtime without altering SQLite source code.

So, if I understand correctly, VFS is not the right direction? Or is it?

Answer (score -1):

May be use a read-only user? I don't know if such role exists in SQL Lite.